# How to end an infinite sudo loop with keyboard and not entering the correct password?

Tags: bash

Try this in a bash:

```sh
while true; do sudo ls; done
```

If not enter the correct password, this loop can not be stopped by Ctrl+C, Ctrl+\ and Ctrl+D.

Edit: This should not happen in a carefully-written realworld script. I am just curious that if there is a way to escape the loop just with some keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: `read -n1 -s -r -p $'Press space to continue...\n' key

if [ "$key" = ' ' ]; then
    # break
    # echo [$key] is empty when SPACE is pressed # uncomment to trace
else
    # Anything else pressed, do whatever else.
    # echo [$key] not empty
fi`
try this :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Thank you, that is what should be done in actual coding. I am just curious that whether I can escape the loop in this special situation, i.e. are there something other than Ctrl+C, Ctrl+\ and Ctrl+D.

Comment: ctrl-z ca b used to pause to current job and send it to background and from there kill it

Comment: That's what I am looking for, thank you! Will you write this as an answer? @JatinMehrotra

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use keyboard shortcut other than  `Ctrl+C, Ctrl+\ and Ctrl+D.`

just use `ctrl-z` tp **pause the process to send it to background and then kill it.**

in your command `while true; do sudo ls; done`

i paused it using ctrl-z and then tried to brought it in foreground using fg.It exits even without killing because when i brought it to foreground only sudo ls was executed..